# Cassandra disk usage per partition key (per "row")

Tags: cassandra, jmx, metrics, diskspace

Is it possible to extract the "total disk usage" for a certain partition key ("row") in Cassandra? I know how to use JMX (JConsole) and nodetool but I only find disk usage per table and keyspace. Since I insert "rows" using a customer id in the partitioning key part I would like to extract the disk usage for a certain customer. Any suggestions using JMX (MBeans)? I'm ok with implementing it myself using JMX/MBeans if anyone has a java implementation suggestion.

Comment: I have a totally different use case but that info would indeed be quite interesting!